# Comparing current unit test result to previous

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

Using QualityTools.UnitTestFramework I would like to test an algorithm's performance. The test consists of verifying that the current version is close "enough" to the previous version with respect to some measurement (a number).

Some sort of history keeping is needed here between consequtive runs of the unit test. What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how detailed your comparison requirements are, I would basically just create an object containing your metric for comparison.
I would then use xml serialization to write it to disk in the form of an xml file. 
At the start up of the test you can deserialize the xml file into a list of your object, and do whatever test run comparisons you need to do

Comment: I'll clarify a bit. I am comparing versions before and after checkins. The comparison is to be run after every checkin so I need a way to access the previous test results - what is the best method\place to store test results for future comparison? (if it's of significance, I'm running the tests on a buildserver)

Comment: I am not aware of any frameworks that offer an out of the box solution to this. But you can write your results to xml files like I described above. However if you need more advanced reporting capabilities it might be an idea to write the results to a database.